# Can an Orc use their Aggressive trait, plus Dash, plus running?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I don't yet have a copy of the monster manual so I apologize if this is explicitly stated in there.

The Orc has an "aggressive" trait that allows it to "move up to its speed toward a hostile creature that it can see." Can this trait be used with Dash, thus allowing an Orc to run 30 feet (in any direction), dash another 30 feet (again, any direction), and then run 30 feet again (but this last burst towards the enemy)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. An orc can do the following on it's turn:

- Bonus Action: Aggressive. Move 30' towards a hostile creature
- Move action: Move 30'
- Action: Dash. Move 30'

There is nothing at all to prevent you from using your turn this way. This give the orc an excellent ability to close a huge distance in their turn if they give up their attack, or close a significant distance and still attack.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. Specifically, **Aggressive** allows movement on a *bonus action*. So the Orc can Dash (its one action for the round) to gain extra movement speed for the round, move, then use Aggressive (its one bonus action for the round). That gives a total of 90 feet of movement.

Note that Dash is additive, not multiplicative. It's easy to misread it as doubling your movement rate for the round, and someone might then conclude that Aggressive lets you move **60 feet** extra instead of 30; but Dash is additive, so it doesn't change your movement rate or influence what you get from Aggressive.